# Is it possible to break a horcrux, and if so what happens then?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Is it possible to break a Horcrux? I don't mean destroy, but if a glass cup is a Horcrux, will it still be whole after it drops from a great height? And then what happens to the Horcrux if it ís broken? If the glass is broken and 7 different people take the shards to their respective homes, who will have the Horcrux?

I got fascinated by this when I was thinking about the placement of a human's soul.  When a person loses his arm, he will still be himself, so he still has a soul, same with legs, hair etc., but it's different with the heart and brain.

Comment: I think its impossible to break that cup..

Comment: "but it's different with the heart" - Does that mean someone loses their soul if they get a heart transplant?

Comment: Good question... I guess not, but maybe people deel different with someone else's heart, worth checking...

Comment: Related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52439/what-makes-a-horcrux-object-almost-indestructable

Comment: @Kevin Maybe it's ok to live with a different soul, and you may not even notice it? But what when your heart is replaced by a machine, like during the transplantation? Spooky to imagine looking down into the surgery rooms trash bin to see a discarded soul on it's ground...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably possible to break a Horcrux, and if it happened,  it would repair itself.

Per Hermione, the only way to destroy a Horcrux is to use something so destructive that it's beyond repairing using normal magical methods, or it will repair itself.

In  Deathly Hallows, when Hermione is talking about means of destroying a Horcrux, she says:

> "It has to be something so destructive that the Horcrux can't repair itself."

If a Horcrux couldn't be damaged, and subsequently repair itself, then there would have been no need for that statement.

Comment: Ah, does canon state that it wil repair itself? I missed that...

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I posted that answer before leaving for work, and just now got back to add the quote

Comment: Thanks man! I gave you The answer because of the quote!

Answer (score 5):

No. The example was the Riddle Diary - it survived being drowned in the toilet and Ginny's other attempts at destruction.