# How did Harry not get crushed in Godric's Hollow?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

It is explained that when Voldemort tried to kill Harry as a baby, his Avada Kedavra rebounded due to Lily's sacrifice.

This caused **two** (important) things to happen:

1. Voldemort got blasted into an unknown state of 'undeadness'
2. The Potter's house got blown to pieces

**How did Harry not get crushed in the events?**

My thoughts are that the destruction was caused by Voldemort, and therefore Harry was protected by Lily's sacrifice.

It's just a funny thought that there could be this little baby with a massive (house) beam on top of him.

**EDIT:**

I seem to remember that the roof got blown-off, so probably not much debris that *could* have hurt him?

> Most of the cottage was still standing, though entirely covered in dark ivy and snow, **but the right side of the top floor had been blown apart**; that, Harry was sure, was where the
>   curse had backfired.
>
> *-Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Bathilda's Secret).*

Comment: Bizarre idea: the blast ***must*** have destroyed baby Harry, but baby Harry is an Horcrux.

Comment: @Voldemort Well Harry was only a quasi-Horcrux, and also apparently making a Horcrux doesn't inherently make the object indestructible, one has to place enchantments on it to make it so...

Comment: I though that the indestructibility is indeed a consequence of being an Horcrux (a natural property), and the enchantments used are for *making* an Horcrux (transferring the soul etc), rather than protecting it. I dunno, haven't read this in ages.

Comment: @Voldemort Not quite; that's what I thought as well, until I asked this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52439/what-makes-a-horcrux-object-almost-indestructable

Comment: Oh alright, then Harry has a pretty hard skull.

Comment: @Voldemort I think old-mate Snape would agree that Harry is 'thick-headed'!

Comment: Also, Snape's pensive memories; he holding Lily on the ground while Harry watches on from his cradle. The room didn't look like a rubble. Another point, I think just creating a horcrux doesnt make it indestructible; its just a soul container. Voldy put up nasty enchantments on those containers to make them nearly indestructible. Nagini was hard to kill but Harry, the horcrux, was destroyed with a simple Avada Kedavra

Comment: Because that would have negated the entire book series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Avada Kedavra rebounded and blew up *AWAY* from Harry.

> **re·bound**
>   *verb:*
>
> - bounce back through the air after hitting a hard surface or object.

.

> *‘Tell him that on the night Lord Voldemort tried to kill him, when
>   Lily cast her own life between them as a shield, **the Killing Curse
>   rebounded upon Lord Voldemort**, and a fragment of Voldemort’s soul was
>   blasted apart from the whole, and latched itself on to the only living
>   soul left in that collapsing building. Part of Lord Voldemort lives
>   inside Harry, and it is that which gives him the power of speech with
>   snakes, and a connection with Lord Voldemort’s mind that he has never
>   understood. And while that fragment of soul, unmissed by Voldemort,
>   remains attached to, and protected by Harry, Lord Voldemort cannot
>   die.’*

Answer (score 1):

According to HP and the Cursed Child, Harry appears to have been protected from falling debris by his crib.

> HAGRID walks through the ruins.
>   ...
>   **Hagrid:** *I want yeh to know — yeh won’t be forgotten — not by me — not by
>   anyfolk.*
>
> And then he hears a sound — the sound of a baby snuffling. HAGRID
>   turns towards it, walking with more intensity now.
>
> **He looks down and stands over the crib.** Which seems to radiate light.
>
> **Hagrid:** *Well. Hello. Yeh must be Harry.*

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54396/20774), the blast itself rebounded from Harry, suggesting that the main blast wave was moving away from him, not toward him.